# problems with CKEditor install in drupal 7

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have installed CKEditor correctly and still get the error:

> The CKEditor component is not installed correctly. Please go to the
>   CKEditor homepage in order to download the latest version. After that
>   you must extract the files to the sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor
>   or sites/all/libraries/ckeditor directory and make sure that the
>   sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js or
>   sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js file exists. Refer to the
>   README.txt file for more information.

I have downloaded and re-downloaded CKEditor several times. Everything is there but still getting error.

I am also confused about exactly what to put in the CKEditor global profile.

Comment: Check this video. this may help you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bzg26YJi2W8

Comment: Are you using CKEditor 4.x perhaps and are you using the freestanding version of the drupal module or WYSIWYG module? What version of the module are you using?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean about "the CK editor global profile."?

Comment: This video may be helpful also. Latest I found on CKEditor installation. https://goo.gl/7tPvu5

Answer (score 4):

It's an issue that happens from time to time.

The instructions that you see are fine:

> Extract the archive and copy its contents into a new folder in the following location:
>   sites/all/libraries/ckeditor
>
> So the actual library can be found at: sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js

If the issue is caused by the message "The version of CKEditor could not be detected." at admin/config/content/wysiwyg.

This [solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/1853550#comment-9003887) helped me yesterday:

1. Open "\sites\all\libraries\ckeditor\ckeditor.js" file in a text
   editor.
2. Add in the first line of the ckeditor.js file:

   // version:'4.4.4',revision:'4391'

and save it.

You can get more help about this module on the [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/371459).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found a solution at https://drupal.org/node/1161738#comment-7857451.

> In the file: .../modules/wysiwyg/editors/ckeditor.inc at about line 81
>
> replace

```
if (preg_match('@version:\'(?:CKEditor
> )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\'([\d]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
```

> with

```
if (preg_match('@version:[\'"](?:CKEditor
> )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:[\'"]([\w]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved the files to sites/all/libraries/ckeditor or sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor and tried clearing your cache by going to /admin/config/development/performance and selecting clear caches? I know that is redudant with the error message. The global profile doesn't normally need changes, it's really the 'advanced' and 'full' profiles that do, these are where you select what kind of buttons you want etc etc.